# Print out Yijing Hexagram Symbols

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I encountered a problem while coding and I can't seem to find where I messed up or even why I get a wrong result.

First, let me explain the task.
It's about "Yijing Hexagram Symbols".
The left one is the original and the right one is the result that my code should give me.
[image]
Basically every "hexagram" contains 6 lines that can be either diveded or not.

So there are a total of

2^6 = 64 possible "hexagrams"

The task is to calculate and code a methode to print all possible combinations.

Thats what I have so far :

```
public class test {
    
    public String toBin (int zahl) {
        if(zahl ==0) return "0";
        if (zahl ==1 ) return "1";
        return ""+(toBin( zahl/2)+(zahl%2));
    }
    
    public void show (String s) {
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()){
            if (c == '1'){
                System.out.println("--- ---");
            }
            if(c=='0'){
                System.out.println("-------");
            }
         
        }
    }
    
    public void ausgeben (){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 64; i++) {
            show (toBin(i));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I test the 'show'-methode with "10" I get 3 lines and not 2 as intended.

```
public class runner {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        test a = new test();
        a.ausgeben();
        a.show("10");
    }
}
```

Another problem I've encoutered is, that since I'm converting to binary i sometimes have not enough lines because for example 10 in binary is 0001010 but the first "0" are missing. How can I implement them in an easy way without changing much ?

I am fairly new to all this so if I didn't explain anything enough or made any mistakes feel free to tell me.

Comment: Typically, the leading zeros are omitted if you're just printing out the numeral.  There are formatting options available if you want the leading zeroes, though.

Comment: That's how it is for my example but the  'show' methode needs them. What do you mean by formatting options? Can you give an example?

Comment: `show("10")` only gives me two lines. I think perhaps you should try printing something after the call to `a.ausgeben()` so that you don't count one of its lines by mistake as part of `show("10")`.

Comment: oh wow ... seems like you are right ! I dont know why but after removing and reimplementing some of the code it seems to not give 3 lines anymore ... Ok so since that is fixed :D how can i implement the missing zeros for hexagrams to be complete ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are many ways to pad a string with zeros, or create a binary string that is already padded with zeros.

For example, you could do something like:

```
public String padToSix( String binStr ) {
    return "000000".substring( 0, 5 - binStr.length() ) + binStr;
}
```

This would check how long your string is, and take as many zeros are needed to fill it up to six from the `"000000"` string.

Or you could simply replace your conversion method (which is recursive, and that's not really necessary) with one that specializes in six-digit numbers:

```
public static String toBin (int zahl) {
    char[] digits = { '0','0','0','0','0','0' };
    int currDigitIndex = 5;

    while ( currDigitIndex >= 0 && zahl > 0 ) {
        digits[currDigitIndex] += (zahl % 2);
        currDigitIndex--;
        zahl /= 2;
    }

    return new String(digits);
}
```

This one modifies the character array ( which initially has only zeros ) from the right to the left. It adds the value of the current bit to the character at the given place. `'0' + 0` is `'0'`, and `'0' + 1` is `'1'`. Because you know in advance that you have six digits, you can start from the right and go to the left. If your number has only four digits, well, the two digits we haven't touched will be `'0'` because that's how the character array was initialized.

There are really a lot of methods to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Ah! I see so i should make use of the fact that is has to be a max 6 digit binary. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 3):

You may find it easier if you use the [`Integer.toBinaryString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString-int-) method combined with the [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) and [`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) methods.

```
String binary = String.format("%6s", Integer.toBinaryString(zahl)).replace(' ', '0');
```

This converts the number to binary, formats it in a field six spaces wide (with leading spaces as necessary), and then replaces the spaces with `'0'.`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem reduces to printing all binary strings of length 6. I would go with this code snippet:

```
  String format = "%06d";
  for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++)         
  {    
    show(String.format(format, Integer.valueOf(Integer.toBinaryString(i))));
    System.out.println();
  }
```

If you don't wish to print leading zeros, replace `String.format(..)` with `Integer.toBinaryString(i)`.

Comment: That's very clever, converting it to a binary string *and then back to an integer* so you can use the `%06d` format. I did something similar, but with a `%6s` format on the binary string, and then replacing the spaces with zeros.

Comment: I'm still new to java so could you explain the variable n ?

Comment: Ah ok cool it is working as intended. So the only point left is me understanding i guess. so you basically take a number i and make it into a binaryString. It could be something like "10100" .What I dont really get is the use of "format" can you explain it to me ?

Comment: @ViktorG - `String.format(..)` formats the number in the desired format, in this case 6-digit with leading zeros. %d is for decimal, 6 specifies that the formatted number should be 6 digit and 0 specifies use leading zeros. Read more on: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-format-string-in-java-printf.html